# Updated to EF 4.2. Then what?

Tags: entity-framework

Ok, so I installed EF 4.2 from NuGet. Just did Install-Package EntityFramework. That's all I've done.

Now what?

How do I know I'm using the new Framework and not the old one.

I have an existing project previously with EF 4.0. I'm also using precompiled views and custom text templates. Everything looks exactly the same after I did the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be no change in existing project. EFv4.2 contains code first mapping approach and DbContext API - neither of those affects existing EFv4.0 projection. It also contains few minor helpers like strongly typed `Include` but you must use them in your code. That is not something that will magically change existing code.

Comment: Oh. What about "The Entity Framework June 2011 CTP includes several SQL generation improvements, especially around optimizing queries over models with table-per-type (TPT) inheritance." (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/announcing-the-microsoft-entity-framework-june-2011-ctp.aspx)

Comment: But the Entity Framework June 2011 CTP **is not EFv4.2**. Features from CTP requires changes in System.Data.Entity.dll and will be released as [part of .NET Framework 4.5](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2011/10/ef-4-5-is-coming-in-the-next-net-4-5-developer-preview/).

Comment: But since you brought it up ;) what do I have to do to get the strongly typed Includes working?

Comment: Once you used NuGet package you should have reference to EntityFramework.dll. Now you need to use `using System.Data.Entity;` and you should have strongly typed `Include` available.

Comment: Sure enough. Thank you! (Now a subscriber.)